# navigate vscode intellisense with custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have changed my cursor movement key from arrow keys to "alt + jkl;", it worked fine, but one problem remained: I was not able to navigate code intellisense with my custom keyboard shortcut, any solutions ? Thanks in advance.

update:  disabled some settings to make things work with @Mark 's answer

```
{
    "key": "alt+i",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which keys you want for what, but try this:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",  // same as downarrow
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },

  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",  // same as tab/select
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },

  {
   "key": "alt+l",
   "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",  // same as uparrow
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
```

Test with the simpler `"when": "suggestWidgetVisible"` to see if that suits you - when there is only one suggestion shown.

Comment: disabled some setting to make things work with @Mark 's answer